# How to change VISIBILITY of textview of specific row in Recyclerview android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have got a RecyclerView which contains two textViews in a row. All I want to do is to change the visibility of single textView of particular row.

E.g. A row contains two textview A and B. I want to change the VISIBILITY of textview A of specific row by passing row position from activity by using code dynamically. I have surfed on internet but didn't find proper way of implementation.

My code:

My Adapter class

```
package com.transit.adarsh.catchmypath;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.List;

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    List<StationData> listItem;
    private Context context;


    public MyAdapter(List<StationData> listItem, Context context) {
        this.listItem = listItem;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        StationData stationData = listItem.get(position);

        holder.platform.setText(stationData.getPlatform());
        holder.station_name.setText(stationData.getEng_station());

        Log.i("DATASSSQ","call");




    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listItem.size();
    }







    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public TextView platform;
        public TextView station_name;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            platform = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.platText);
            station_name = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.station_name);


        }
    }


}
```

StationData class:

```
package com.transit.adarsh.catchmypath;

public class StationData {

    private String platform;
    private String eng_station;
    private String hin_station;
    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;

    public StationData( String platform, String eng_station, String hin_station, double latitude, double longitude) {
        this.platform = platform;
        this.eng_station = eng_station;
        this.hin_station = hin_station;
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;

    }

    public String getPlatform() {
        return platform;
    }

    public String getEng_station() {
        return eng_station;
    }

    public String getHin_station() {
        return hin_station;
    }

    public double getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }
```

}

RecyclerView Class:

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
stationDataList = new ArrayList<>();


stationDataList.add(new StationData("Kopar","PF 2","Kopar",
                "कोपर",19.211237,73.077613));

stationDataList.add(new StationData("Diva","PF 2","Diva",
                "दिवा",19.188439,73.042223));

stationDataList.add(new StationData("Mumbra","PF 2","Mumbra",
                "मुंब्रा",19.190266,73.023015));

stationDataList.add(new StationData("Kalva","PF 2","Kalva",
                "कलवा",19.196362,72.998234));

stationDataList.add(new StationData("Thane","PF 4","Thane",
                "ठाणे",19.186472,72.97547));


adapter = new MyAdapter(stationDataList, this);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I'm newbie to programmaing world, it would be great if anyone helps me out.

Comment: How do you pass row position from activity to adapter?

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman  I didn't implemented any method to pass the row, just stuck with that thing only how to design the code.

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store Property [**visibility**] inside model and make decision based on that.

```
class StationData {

    ...

    private int visibility = View.VISIBLE;

    public int getVisibility() {
        return visibility;
    }

    public void setVisibility(int visibility) {
        this.visibility = visibility;
    }

    ...

}
```

Handle visibility here and update view.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final SuggestionHomeAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    final StationData stationData = listItem.get(position);

    holder.station_name.setVisibility(stationData.getVisibility());

    ...
}
```

call `updateVisibility` from activity with position and visibility.

```
public void updateVisibility(int position, int visibility) {
    listItem.get(position).setVisibility(visibility);
    notifyItemChanged(position);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, will try and let you know

Comment: Welcome @Adarsh, it's really glad to help you